# How to restrict access to certain subnets on a VPN connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Assume a connection between the on-premises datacenter (DC) and the virtual private cloud (VPC), through a virtual private gateway (VGW) over a VPN.

Now, will a person sitting on the on-premises DC, be able to access all the subnets on the VPC through VGW?

I have few subnets in the VPC which I don't want him to access. So, how do I go about restricting him. Any ideas?

Comment: which VPN software involved in the infrastructure? Because depend on that the possibility change. Have you the opportunity to use a firewall?

Comment: @AtomiX84 I'm actually talking about the VPN from VGW to Client gateway provided by AWS. With BGP routing over IPSec to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

You get this configurations available on `AWS`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html

that seems to be the right one to your goal is called: `AWS VPN CloudHub`

Here a short description of design available:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPN_CloudHub.html

It seems AWS allow you to create different `VGW` for different subnet, so I think you have to create a new VGW point only for the subnet you want to give access to the people in `on-premises DC`

Comment: We do have the same VGW connected to multiple Client gateways using VPN. Yes we are using the VPN CloudHub design. But I don't find the use of adding another VGW since access control is not possible in VGW. Access control only is possible in Network ACLs which are at the subnet level. Now, I can restrict his access using N'ACLs but the only downside is that we are having 15 N'ACLs associated with over 25 subnets, and I have to add inbound/outbound restrictions to all 15 of them. I was expecting if there is an ideal way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, and as per you are paying customer of AWS service, If you are not already do, contact the business support of AWS service to help you out to find a solution.